# horizontal scrolling not working

Tags: visual-c++, scroll

this code instead of doing horizontal scrolling is doing vertical scrolling, please give me any suggestion what i am doing wrong. i want to do horizontal scrolling.

```
 void CFormGridColumnPreviewDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar*    
 pScrollBar)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

int nDelta;
int nMaxPos = m_rcOriginalRect.Width() - m_nCurWidth;

switch (nSBCode)
{
case SB_LINERIGHT:
    if (m_nScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
        return;

    nDelta = min(max(nMaxPos/20,5),nMaxPos-m_nScrollPos);
    break;

case SB_LINELEFT:
    if (m_nScrollPos <= 0)
        return;
    nDelta = -min(max(nMaxPos/20,5),m_nScrollPos);
    break;
case SB_PAGERIGHT:
    if (m_nScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
        return;
    nDelta = min(max(nMaxPos/10,5),nMaxPos-m_nScrollPos);
    break;
case SB_THUMBTRACK:
case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
    nDelta = (int)nPos - m_nScrollPos;
    break;

case SB_PAGELEFT:
    if (m_nScrollPos <= 0)
        return;
    nDelta = -min(max(nMaxPos/10,5),m_nScrollPos);
    break;

     default:
    return;
}
m_nScrollPos += nDelta;
SetScrollPos(SB_HORZ,m_nScrollPos,TRUE);
ScrollWindow(0,-nDelta);

CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

void CFormGridColumnPreviewDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{ 
CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

// TODO: Add your message handler code here
m_nCurWidth = cx;

SCROLLINFO si;
si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
si.fMask = SIF_ALL; 
si.nMin = 0;
si.nMax = m_rcOriginalRect.Width();
si.nPage = cx;
si.nPos = 0;
SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE); 
}
```

Comment: Hard to see what ScrollWindow() might do, but swapping the two arguments or just getting rid of it sounds like a solution.

Comment: ScrollWindow(-nDelta, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this results for you:

```js
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(AddTabDlg, CDialog)
 ON_WM_SIZE()
 ON_WM_VSCROLL()
 ON_WM_HSCROLL()

END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// AddTabDlg message handlers

BOOL AddTabDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
 CDialog::OnInitDialog();
 
 GetWindowRect(m_rect);
 m_nScrollPos = 0;
 m_nScrollPosH = 0;

 return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void AddTabDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
 CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

 // TODO: Add your message handler code here.
 m_nCurHeight = cy;

 m_nCurWidth = cx;

 int nScrollMax;
 if (cy < m_rect.Height())
 {
  nScrollMax = m_rect.Height() - cy;
 }
 else
  nScrollMax = 0;

 int nScrollMaxH;
 if (cx < m_rect.Width())
 {
  nScrollMaxH = m_rect.Width() - cx;
 }
 else
  nScrollMaxH = 0;

 SCROLLINFO si;
 si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
 si.fMask = SIF_ALL; // SIF_ALL = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
 si.nMin = 0;
 si.nMax = nScrollMax;
 si.nPage = si.nMax / 10;
 si.nPos = 0;
 SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);

 SCROLLINFO sih;
 sih.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
 sih.fMask = SIF_ALL; // SIF_ALL = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
 sih.nMin = 0;
 sih.nMax = nScrollMaxH;
 sih.nPage = sih.nMax / 10;
 sih.nPos = 0;
 SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &sih, TRUE);
}

void AddTabDlg::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
 // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default.
 int nDelta;
 int nMaxPos = m_rect.Height() - m_nCurHeight;

 switch (nSBCode)
 {
 case SB_LINEDOWN:
  if (m_nScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
   return;
  nDelta = min(nMaxPos / 100, nMaxPos - m_nScrollPos);
  break;

 case SB_LINEUP:
  if (m_nScrollPos <= 0)
   return;
  nDelta = -min(nMaxPos / 100, m_nScrollPos);
  break;

 case SB_PAGEDOWN:
  if (m_nScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
   return;
  nDelta = min(nMaxPos / 10, nMaxPos - m_nScrollPos);
  break;

 case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
  nDelta = (int)nPos - m_nScrollPos;
  break;

 case SB_PAGEUP:
  if (m_nScrollPos <= 0)
   return;
  nDelta = -min(nMaxPos / 10, m_nScrollPos);
  break;

 default:
  return;
 }
 m_nScrollPos += nDelta;
 SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, m_nScrollPos, TRUE);
 ScrollWindow(0, -nDelta);
 CDialog::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

void AddTabDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
 // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default.
 int nDeltaH;
 int nMaxPosH = m_rect.Width() - m_nCurWidth;

 switch (nSBCode)
 {
 case SB_LINERIGHT:
  if (m_nScrollPosH >= nMaxPosH)
   return;
  nDeltaH = min(nMaxPosH / 100, nMaxPosH - m_nScrollPosH);
  break;

 case SB_LINELEFT:
  if (m_nScrollPosH <= 0)
   return;
  nDeltaH = -min(nMaxPosH / 100, m_nScrollPosH);
  break;

 case SB_RIGHT:
  if (m_nScrollPosH >= nMaxPosH)
   return;
  nDeltaH = min(nMaxPosH / 10, nMaxPosH - m_nScrollPosH);
  break;

 case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
  nDeltaH = (int)nPos - m_nScrollPosH;
  break;

 case SB_LEFT:
  if (m_nScrollPosH <= 0)
   return;
  nDeltaH = -min(nMaxPosH / 10, m_nScrollPosH);
  break;

 default:
  return;
 }
 m_nScrollPosH += nDeltaH;
 SetScrollPos(SB_HORZ, m_nScrollPosH, TRUE);
 ScrollWindow(-nDeltaH, 0);
 CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

It's working at the same time, horizontal and vertical scrollbars ;)